# ReactNative: ERROR: Failed to install the app

Tags: firebase, react-native

Every time I run these two commands

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app
yarn add @react-native-firebase/firestore
```

And then I try to execute the project, it gives a gigantic error and in the end this appears:

[image]

My code is the same when you create a new project, the difference is that it doesn't have that standard content.
I removed that 'React$Node', **deixando o aquela linha assim 'const App = () => {', mas não funciona também. Eu utilizo o expo e já utilizei o cli e nunca vi o App.js estruturado desta maneira**

I have already created several projects and I always repeat the same documentation process and always give this error

Someone please help me, I really need to solve this

Comment: Please double check that all is in English, or use formatting to help with reading and understanding the purpose of the short non-English parts. I do not get it, but I assume that I simply lack the technical understanding. Also, please consider providing textual information as text, not as picture of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is `The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K` error

modify `android/app/build.gralde`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true -> add this
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' -> add this
}
```

Comment: That is good for you, GobsRuiz. Now, will you also do something for the community which helped you and clean up the distracting language problem inside your question? I highlighted it for you convenience.